# Issue with mysql query and python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Have an issue with the following mysql query in python 2.7 using mysql connector:

Here is my code:

```
query  = "INSERT INTO %s " % cfg['mysql.table']
query += "('hostname', 'metric', 'timestamp', 'average', 'peakhigh', 'peaklow', 'gsamp', 'zsamp', 'nsamp') " 
query += """VALUES ( %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%Y%m%dT%h:%i:%s'), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )"""

print query
for record in DATA:
    print record
    cursor.execute(query, list(record))
```

And my output:

```
INSERT INTO perf ('hostname', 'metric', 'timestamp', 'average', 'peakhigh', 'peaklow', 'gsamp', 'zsamp', 'nsamp') VALUES ( %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%Y%m%dT%h:%i:%s'), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )
('somehost', 'cpu.utilization', '20160531T12:00:00', 9, 29, 0, 900, 0, 0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./perfquery.py", line 427, in <module>
    mysql_dataload(cfg, CNX, DATA)
  File "./perfquery.py", line 369, in mysql_dataload
    cursor.execute(query, record)
  File "/usr/local/python-2.76/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 504, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
  File "/usr/local/python-2.76/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 70, in __call__
    "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

I'm guessing the str_to_date is throwing the monkey wrench but I've played around with a half dozen other approaches to doing this and can't find something that works.

Thx for any help.

Comment: what is **record**? Is that a list?

Comment: Actually my bad, record at that point is a tuple. I now convert it to a list and still get the same error. (Code above has been updated)

Answer (score 0):

I guess INSERT INTO %s <- is not set. You are setting only values from record, but not the table name.

Comment: I print out the query and it appears fine.

Comment: Have you tried to escape your SQL call like this:  STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%%Y%%m%%dT%%h:%%i:%%s')

Comment: I ended up just reworking the date string coming from the storage device and formatting it to the default the datetime format expects, avoiding the use of STR_TO_DATE, it's working now. Next time I'll try escaping as you mentioned.